# Check if there are any array values set PHP

Tags: php, arrays, is-empty

What's the best/easiest way to check if an array has any values set? I set the keys myself, no matter what so I can't go based on the keys. My code will show what I'm doing, and want to do:

```
 $array = array(
                "Birthday" => $row3['birthday'],
                "Sex" => $row3['sex'],
                "Lives In" => $row3['livesIn']
            );
    if(empty($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value)
            {       
                echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td><td>".$value."</td></tr>";   
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "This user has not provided any information yet";  
    }
```

So, for instance, if `$row3['birthday']`, `$row3['sex']`, `$row3['livesIn']` are all empty, then it should render the first if statement as false, and move to the else statement.

Comment: This question is kinda old, but it helped me, and it is actually NOT a duplicate of the marked question. The **possible duplicate** question is asking how to find if there are any *empty* values in an array, whereas this question asks how to find if there are any *non-empty* values. The solution in the marked question cannot be applied to this question. The accepted answer on this question works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter), which with one parameter will remove all array values that are equal to `false` when typecasted to a boolean:

```
if( count( array_filter( $array)) == 0) {
    echo "Array contained 'empty' values\n";
}
```

You can [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) to find out which values will become boolean `false`.